# How to make images change on click with variables

Tags: javascript

I need to make a "slideshow" of sorts, where images must cycle through when clicked. For example, I need it to cycle through 5 images.

It's been suggested that I use an `onclick` function that makes a variable increase by one every click, so when loaded, it is the first image, when clicked once it is the second image, etc.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Andrew... I'd suggest just google for the slideshow images.. Either you will get some js plugins or you will find some code.. In SO people tend to help only when you find some problem in your code and you are not able to achieve it.. So you need to try first.. :) And once you are stuck anywhere we can help you.. :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically a good question here includes a show of effort; you should add some code showing what you've tried already. For more tips, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here Jesse. And I have to do it this way.

Comment: Your proposed solution seems solid enough to me, try it! Another hint: use an array `["url/image1.png", "url/image2.png", ...]` to store the paths to the images and set the image element `.src = images[i]` where `i` is the variable you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is have an array of 5 images, and a variable to keep track on what index you are on:

```
var imgArray = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5'];

var currentIndex = 0;
```

Then add a `onclick` event to your image (*for example with an `id` of `"img"`*), and increment that counter. Next apply a [modulus (remainder)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator to allow cycling. This means that when the counter goes over the length of the array it will "cycle" back to zero.

```
document.getElementById("img").onclick = function() {
    currentIndex++;
    currentIndex = currentIndex % imgArray.length;
    this.src = imgArray[currentIndex];
}
```

[**Example using 3 images**](http://jsfiddle.net/pxx71p8c/)

Answer (score 0):

Add your **img** in webpage with blank source.

```
<img id = "image" src = "" />
<br />
<button id = "button">Next image</button>
```

Then write the script as following.

```
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var imagesList = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];

    i = 0;
    img.src = imagesList[i];

    function nextImg(){
       img.src = imagesList[i+1];
       i = i+1;
       if(i == imagesList.length){
         i = 0;
         img.src = imagesList[i];
       }
    }

  button.onclick = nextImg;
```